# Can't convert from opencv to PIL Image to feed properly to a custom model ( InceptionV3 )

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

I'm using opencvs' *VideoCapture* to read a video ***frame by frame*** and feed each image to a custom pre-trained ***InceptionV3 Model*** for image classification ( two labels ). I'm unable to PROPERLY convert each frame from opencv format to PIL, I've tried lot of options from around web. None seem to work.

The model always picks a wrong label, when I try to classify from each frame of a video.

Where as, when I save the image read as a jpeg and then feed that static image to the model, it properly classifies the label then. I tried the normal conversion of BGR to RGB and then use PIL to read the image.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../y2mate.com - chihuahua_at_play_tony_taken_02192010_from_pentimfall2009_video_3avi_iCOXj63oYEM_360p.mp4')


width, height = 200, 200

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
    print("Error opening video stream or file")


# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
    print("Error opening video stream or file")




# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()



    # Convert to RGB
    cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Read image in PIL format
    pil_im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im)

    # Predict using pre-trained model
    predics = predict(Inception_Model, cv2_im)


    print(predics)

    if np.max(predics) > 0.90:

        predicted_label = labels[ np.argmax(predics) ]

        cv2.putText(frame,

                    'Detected ' + predicted_label,

                    (50,250),

                    font,
                    2,

                    (255,0,255),
                    2,

                    cv2.LINE_AA)



    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Dog Face',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The two labels are : 'Chihuahua' and 'Maltese'; trained in the same order

No matter what the frame data is;

the Actual Result looks like this:

```
[0.22820102 0.771799  ]
[0.17714396 0.82285607]
[0.11787692 0.8821231 ]
[0.11390335 0.88609666]
[0.1003077  0.89969236]
[0.0998676 0.9001325]
[0.05119308 0.94880694]
[0.11403728 0.8859627 ]
[0.03555993 0.96444005]
[0.04067587 0.95932406]
[0.029842 0.970158]
[0.01746762 0.9825324 ]
[0.06942239 0.9305776 ]
[0.01813542 0.9818646 ]
[0.0055009 0.9944991]
[0.00557377 0.99442625]
[0.004916 0.995084]
[0.01140862 0.9885914 ]
[0.01956638 0.98043364]
```

where as, for this data ( which is a video of chihuahua )

the output should be:

```
[0.999444, 0.005509]
```

when I try to read the saved jpg image ( saved from some frames of previous video )

I get the actual output:

```
stat_img = load_img('/home/amith/LAI/LOCV/practice/Test-91.jpg', target_size=(220,220))

labels [ np.argmax( predict(Inception_Model, stat_img) ) ], predict(Inception_Model, stat_img)

('Chihuahua', array([9.9999905e-01, 9.4589092e-07], dtype=float32))
```

when I try to read the converted pillow image as a numpy array, I always end up seeing bunch of zeros and nothing else. This exactly shows why each frame is only classified as one label. The conversion from cv to PIL is messing up something that it won't take the actual pixel values, but I don't know exactly how to convert from cv to PIL.

I'd highly appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Note: I'm a 100 % sure that the DL model is working absolutely fine and it's not its fault that classification is so off.

For anyone interested in the video: [Chihuahua](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCOXj63oYEM)

Comment: Your video appears to be 640x480 whereas your JPEG appears to be 220x220.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the response. I don't think the dimensions of the data would matter in terms of format in which the data is read. 

The inception model I trained was with images of shape 220 * 220, that's the reason why I read each frame from opencv , reshaped them and then tried to convert them to PIL format; but with no luck